# JavaScript AWS is not defined when putting AWS cdn in JS file

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

### **Working code**

`index.html`

```
<body>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.169.0.min.js">
</script>
</body>
```

---

**app.js**

---

```
AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
  secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
});
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

s3.putObject({
  Bucket: 'MyBucket',
  Key: 'del2.txt',
  Body: "base64data",
  ACL: 'public-read',
}, function(res) {
  console.log(arguments);
  console.log('Successfully uploaded package.');
});
```

---

What i am trying to achieve now is put the **aws-sdk.min.js** into my **app.js** for easy distribution.

**My non-working app.js**

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src ="aws cdn";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
//rest of existing app.js code.
```

This code is giving me **AWS not defined error**.

**What I have tried**

1. I looked at the html it is correctly adding aws.min.js in the html.
2. I tried with add min.js with `document.write()` but same error.
3. Tried with loading the min.js with async mode. not helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your modified js should be like

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
script.onload =function() {
     //your existing app.js code.
};
```